# Linq for nested loop

Tags: c#, linq

I have a loop as follows:

```
foreach(x in myColl) 
{
    foreach(var y in x.MyList) 
    {
        result.Add(x.MyKey + y)
    }
}
```

That means within my inner loop I need access to a property of the current outer element.

I´m looking for a LINQ-statement but I´m unsure on it. I tried it by using

```
result = myColl
    .SelectMany(x => x.MyList)
    .SelectMany(x => /* how to get the key of the outer loop here */ + x)
```

Comment: Nested for each are easy to read, where a linq query may be more obscure. Why do you feel you need to use linq in this case?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is easy with query expressions:

```
(from x in myColl
 from y in x.MyList
 select x.MyKey + y).ToList()
```

This works because this translates to:

```
myColl
.SelectMany(x => x.MyList.Select(item => new { List = x, Item = item }))
.Select(x => ...) //rest of the query, whatever you like
```

The key is to keep both the list as well as the list items. Channel them through the query using an anonymous type (or any other container).

Comment: You need to name the anonymous properties.

Comment: They get their default name from the expression. This does work. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that second `SelectMany` should just be a `Select`, or it's likely to translate to the `SelectMany` overload in Tormod's answer.

Comment: The names doesn't have to be stated but the first `SelectMany` must receive a predicate which returns an `IEnumerable` and it doesn't...

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea what exactly the translation results in. It does not matter for this question. And Tamir is right, the first SelectMany is completely wrong and I got 5 upvotes :)

Comment: The Second code (linq-Methodchain) should be
`myColl.SelectMany(x => x.MyList, (x, y) => x.MyKey + y)`.
No need for annonymous types.

Comment: @CSharpie hm, that might be better. I'll leave the answer as is because this demonstrates the temporary object technique. That technique is required in certain cases, for example in case of a `where` before the final `select`.

Comment: @CSharpie Furthermore this (new) appraoch is already mentioned by Tormod within his answer.

Answer (score 5):

There is an [overload of SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534631(v=vs.100).aspx) which allows access to the "parent" element.
ListOfList.SelectMany(list=>list.InnerList,**(lst,element)=> HandleInnerListAndElementFromIt(lst,element)**)

```
 result = myColl.SelectMany(x => x.MyList,(x1,x2)=>DoSomething(x1,x2));
```

EDIT Added:

For your concrete example it looks like this:

```
result = myColl.SelectMany(x=>x.MyList,(x,y)=>x.MyKey+y));
```

Notice that there are *two lambda parameters to the SelectMany method call*.

First lambda will take the "x" and return a new Enumerable. **x=>x.MyList**

The second lambda takes the "x" and "y" and produce a new result. **(x,y)=>x.MyKey+y**

Comment: I have to admit, although it looks cool and does what I need it´s quite hard to read.

Answer (score 5):

This is when I personally prefer query syntax

```
var result = from x in myCol1
             from y in x.MyList
             select x.MyKey + y;
```