# Using linq to avoid nested loop

Tags: c#, linq

I want to create a method to find the index of two numbers whose sum is `target`.

So, I have created this method:

```
public static int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < nums.Length; j++)
        {
            if (j == i) continue;

            if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target)
            {
                return new[] { i, j };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which works fine. However, I am trying to learn myself some LINQ and can't figure it out. I looked at various examples, but I always end up stuck because I am using the same array twice. So I don't know what to select and how to access it twice while also making sure it doesn't go through the same indexes twice.

Any help getting a LINQ from the above loops would be appreciated.

Sample data:

```
var nums = new [] { 2, 7, 11, 15 };
var target = 9;
```

Comment: Added to main question @D-Shih

Comment: Ok I saw it thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is as a single LINQ statement, using `SelectMany`. With LINQ, you have to flip your mind upside down... just type `return` and then go from there.

```
public static int[] TwoSumWithLinq(int[] nums, int target)
{
    return nums.SelectMany
    (
        (m, i) => nums.Select
            (
                (n,j) => new { n, m, i, j }
            )
    )
    .Where
    (
        r => (r.i != r.j) && (r.m + r.n == target)
    )
    .Select
    (
        r => new int[] { r.i, r.j }
    )
    .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

[Link to working example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/J4cf5C)

Comment: Pretty clean solution

Answer (score 3):

The `LINQ` equivalent of your loop would be:

```
from x in nums.Select((n, i) => new { Number = n, Index = i })
from y in nums.Select((n, i) => new { Number = n, Index = i })
where x.Index != y.Index && x.Number + y.Number == target
select new [] { x.Index, y.Index }
```

But this requires the creation of anonymous type instance so I would say the loop version is much better and efficient.

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: It looks nice, indeed! I have a question which may seem noobish. How would the code look like in "C# version of LINQ"?

Comment: Please check C# code sample and output. https://dotnetfiddle.net/EXc0ES

Comment: @csharpbd I was referring to replacing the `from` and `where` to C# methods `Select`, `Where` etc.

Comment: @user9248102 There are two types of LINQ syntax: query syntax, and method syntax. Query syntax is what's being used in Selman's answer. Method syntax is what you're asking for.

Comment: That's correct @JohnH that's exactly what I was asking for.

Comment: @user9248102 you can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35085579/linq-for-nested-loop) for that. Most of the time query syntax is more readable and I prefer that but for inner loops like in this case I think query syntax looks better.

Comment: This isn't quite equivalent. You'll end up with two sets of results here: { 0, 1 }, and { 1, 0 } - just needs to select the first result. That said, I agree with you that the loop version is much better.

Comment: You're right @JohnH but as you said I can take the first result. Also, `SelectMany` is one of the methods I have troubles understanding and it would be nice to see how this would be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the slightly cleaner version:

```
public static int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target)
{
    return
    (
        from i in Enumerable.Range(0, nums.Length)
        from j in Enumerable.Range(0, nums.Length)
        where i != j && nums[i] + nums[j] == target
        select new [] { i, j }
    ).FirstOrDefault();
 }
```

Comment: Time complexity of this solution is O(N^4), why would you evaluate `Enumerable.Range(0, nums.Length)` twice

Comment: @MrinalKamboj - It's an array - `.Length` is O(1).

Comment: looping is done in the `Enumerable.Range` not `nums.Length`, which in itself part of another outer Enumeration.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj - Yes, but that would make it only `O(N^2)`. Why do you say it is `O(N^4)`?

Comment: `from i in Enumerable.Range(0, nums.Length)` would be `O(N^2)`, since you are not materializing the collection, it would be multiple enumeration. In my understanding `Enumerable.Range(0, nums.Length)` shall be materialized before its used in the Linq query

Comment: @MrinalKamboj - No, that's not correct. `from i in Enumerable.Range(0, nums.Length)` is simply `O(N)`.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target)
{
    int[] indexes = Enumerable.Range(0, nums.Length).ToArray();

    var result =  from i in indexes
                  from j in indexes
                  where i != j && (nums[i] + nums[j]) == target
                  select new []
                  {
                      i,
                      j
                  };

    return result.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Please note that the method will return `null` if there aren't any members in the array that will match the condition (sum of members = target)

Comment: I am not down-voter, but your solution would have much higher time complexity, for higher values of N would tend to be slower, moreover when overload of `Select` / `SelectMany` provides the index, then its more elegant to use